# jquery: check all/none checkbox only works once

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a check all/none checkbox. However, it only works once: it can check all, then uncheck all, but then cannot check them all again.

http://jsfiddle.net/SDEwB/

```
check all/none: <input type = "checkbox" id = "check_all_none"></input>
<br/>
<input type = "checkbox" class = "others"></input><br/>
<input type = "checkbox" class = "others"></input>


$('#check_all_none').change(function () {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $('.others').attr("checked", true);
    }
    else{
        $('.others').removeAttr("checked"); 
       // $('.others').attr("checked", false); // tried this, too
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
 $('#check_all_none').click(function () {
if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    $('.others').prop("checked", true);
}
else{
    $('.others').removeAttr("checked");
 }

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SDEwB/1/)

Answer (score 7):

use

```
$('#check_all_none').change(function () {
    $('.others').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zC6Xy/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of attr.

```
if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    $('.others').prop("checked", true);
}
else{
    $('.others').prop("checked", false);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SDEwB/3/

**Update**:

Like Arun said, this is better:

```
$('#check_all_none').change(function () {
    $('.others').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple way to check all wanted check box:

```
$("#check_all_none").click(function() {
    $(".others").attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/azkPR/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type = "checkbox" id = "check_all_none" onclick="checkAll(this)" />
<input type = "checkbox" class = "others" name="chk" /><br/>
<input type = "checkbox" class = "others" name="chk" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
function checkAll(t){
    if ( $(t).is(':checked') ){
        $('.others').prop("checked", true);
    }
    else{
        $('.others').attr('checked', false);
    }   
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function checkAll(t){
   var checkboxes= document.getElementsByName('chk');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if(t.checked==true){
            checkboxes[i].checked = true;
        }else{
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have declare function. Cause you can easily reuse this code any where. There have two types of code i have written(JQuery and JavaScript). Both are working fine. If you don't need to use any jQuery library so use JavaScript code.

Comment: Explain your answer a bit.